# Does it matter what input value is used for the base case in proof by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let's say I had a problem where values are being considered for n>=4 and I am able to make the base case work for an input value of n = 4 and n =6. In this case should I use my input value for the basis case as n = 4 or n = 6? If I pick to do n = 6 for my basis case would I be considered incorrect, or it does not matter for proof by induction?

Comment: Welcome to Math. S.E.  If your base case is $n=6$, then you would prove the proposition for all $n\ge6$

Comment: You can always show more than one base case if your proof is catered towards that. I would work through $n=4,5,6$ though if you wanted to show this, just for completion. But in general,you want your base case to be the lowest possible number that is valid to use.

Comment: @C Squared Is there a reason why we would want to make our base case the lowest possible valid value? Would it be mathematically incorrect to pick a higher value, is what I am confused about?

Comment: As @J.W.Tanner says, choosing a higher case will prove it for all n greater than that case. If you choose a case where $n\geq 6$, you wont have proved every case, and you will have to go back and prove the $n=5$ and $n=4$ cases individually, because they are not included in the induction proof.

Answer (score 0):

When you prove some proposition $P (n) $ by induction, you are essentially showing that the proposition holds true for infinitely many elements $n_0, n_1, ... $. The base case determines who is the first element $n_0$.